# How to leave a current employer?

Tags: communication, quitting, resignation

I work in a commission based workplace and while working up to 9 hours a day for 5 days a week and not seeing a single client. The other staff have been kind, and while there has been some rough patches with the owner, I'm on decent terms with them, but I'm unsure of the proper way to leave beyond giving a two weeks notice.

Is there anyway to make the transition of my leaving any smoother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to offer to document everything you have been working on when you give notice (rather than being asked to).  Make sure that you drive effective handover of anything you have in the pipeline.  It seems that given you are commission based and have not seen any clients, then it's likely that you a) haven't been there long; and b) don't have much to hand over.  However, there may be leads that can be followed up by the other staff.

Also, I would recommend not extending your notice period.  I have done this in the past and it was a mistake.  Just give your two weeks, hand over everything and move to your next job.  Really, it doesn't sound like there is much more you can do than be polite and don't burn any bridges.

Comment: This sounds spot-on. By offering to help document anything that depends upon you, you are making a gesture of good faith. Don't give more than the two weeks required notice, as it's often detrimental to give excessive notice. If you don't have much in terms of savings to fall back on, get a new job lined up before you resign from your current one. Provide any process specific documentation, make sure to provide all client info if it's not already documented, don't poach clients, etc. Best of luck in your future job!

Comment: @Dogbert Oh, I forgot to say not to extend your notice period.  Will edit it in.